# Readmore.js doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use Readmore.js, a jQuery plugin for collapsing and expanding long blocks of text with "Read more" and "Close" links, for the first time and can't really understand the reason why nothing changes.

I try to get article contents collapsed and Read more button to appear.

I checked twice if the source files are there for both jQuery and readmore.

```js
$('article').readmore();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js"></script>


<article>
  <p class="giftheading"><b>Name Surname</b> celebrates <b>Event</b> in <b>5</b> days!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis
    nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: "Readmore.js won't work" - please assume that most of us have no idea what readmore is and elaborate. It doesn't do what is expected? It throws an error?

Comment: Name edited. Do You think this is explanatory enough?

Comment: I attempted to bring jQuery up but it didn't help

Comment: This library has [multiple github issues open](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+jquery) saying it doesn't work with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: @ArturGalata no that is not explanatory enough.  Are you getting console errors?  Network 404s?  What?  You need to be *specific* about what is happening because we can't see your screen.

Comment: Your code works with an older version of jQuery.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Edited js as shown in the github, but it remains the same. Well, not much to do but write some js myself, I guess. Thanks for Your time.

Comment: This PR apparently corrects the jquery version problem: https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/pull/206

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried to apply these corrections, but it didn't help. Will have to roll back to jQuery 2.1 probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works with an older version of jQuery (1.11.1):

```js
$('article').readmore();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js"></script>


<article>
  <p class="giftheading"><b>Name Surname</b> celebrates <b>Event</b> in <b>5</b> days!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis
    nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
</article>
```

It also works with 2.1.1 version:

```js
$('article').readmore();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js"></script>


<article>
  <p class="giftheading"><b>Name Surname</b> celebrates <b>Event</b> in <b>5</b> days!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis
    nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis consectetur nunc facilisis imperdiet. Donec sed arcu augue. Vestibulum tristique lobortis nulla eget pellentesque. Quisque consectetur vitae dui a porttitor. Suspendisse vel imperdiet
    dui, semper maximus sem. Aliquam in quam ornare, fringilla tellus sit amet, sodales ligula.</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Readmore doesn't initiate on a block unless its height is larger than the `collapsedHeight` plus `heightMargin`. Using no options this works out to be 216px.